# Provide the numeric values of a column instead of automated list number in unlist process

Tags: r

Through out this process:

```
library("spacyr")
library("dplyr", warn.conflicts = FALSE)

mytext <- data.frame(text = c("test text", "section 2 sending"), id = c(32,41))
```

is it possible to melt the input dataframe my text using as separation for every row the space between terms?

Example output:

```
32 test
    32 text
    41 section
    41 2
    41 sending
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy to to do with the `tidyr` library

```r
mytext <- data.frame(text = c("test text", "section 2 sending"), 
                     id = c(32,41))

tidyr::separate_rows(mytext, text)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   text       id
#>   <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1 test       32
#> 2 text       32
#> 3 section    41
#> 4 2          41
#> 5 sending    41
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(mytext, "text", sep=" ", "long")
#      text id
#1:    test 32
#2:    text 32
#3: section 41
#4:       2 41
#5: sending 41
```